# image too bright when exporting grayscale matlab images with matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

I am using  `matlab2tikz` to export my MATLAB plots to tikz. This works pretty well as long as I am using the colormap `jet` inside MATLAB. Unfortunately, as soon as I am using grayscale, the resulting images become way to bright.

This is how the matlab2tikz output looks like:

[image: matlab2tikz output]

This is how the figure looks in MATLAB:

[image: how it should look like]

The resulting tikz file is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[% width=0.7\textwidth, height=0.2\textheight, axis on
top, scale only axis, xmin=0.5, xmax=450.5, y dir=reverse, ymin=0.5,
ymax=375.5, title={true disparity} ] \addplot graphics
[xmin=0.5,xmax=450.5,ymin=0.5,ymax=375.5] {trueDisp-1.png}; \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I don't see what is happening here. I executed matlab2tikz multiple times and each time the result ended up to bright. If I use the jet colormap on the same image, the resulting png image is correct.

Did anybody ever experienced the same behaviour and/or knows how to solve it?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. Did you use `imshow` to create the plot? I did a quick test with just a gradient (`imshow(repmat(linspace(0,1,100),100,1))`), and the most recent version of `matlab2tikz` created  a perfectly fine PNG. Do you have the newest `matlab2tikz`?

Comment: This looks like an output setting - it's not simply too bright, it's not even greyscale, but monochrome.

Comment: Can you upload the resulting tikz file somewhere? Inspection of that file will reveal the actual colors used, and thus the nature of the problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am using `imagesc()` to crate the plots. I a using v0.4.1, as far as I found this is the latest version?!

Comment: @JLDiaz I added the resulting tikz file to my opening post!

Comment: 0.4.1 is the same that I have, and `imagesc(repmat(linspace(0,1,100),100,1));colormap(gray);matlab2tikz('test.tex');` works fine here (Matlab 2012a, if that matters).

Comment: I ran your code and it works for me as well. I re-ran the code for my plot and it still gives the same error as shown above. I will investigate this further.

Comment: Okay I found the error source: the data is uint8 which apparently matlab2tikz can't handle properly. After converting the data to double everything worked. However I still think it is strange that uint8 data can't be handled!

Comment: Good you worked it out. Do you want to post that as an answer, or should we close the question as off-topic (which it sort of is, given that it's a possible `matlab2tikz` bug)?  You could file a bug report at https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz/issues

Comment: I think we could close it as off-topic, as I agree that it is off-topic. (it will still appear in search then right?)

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know closed questions aren't deleted.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Closed questions with low activity/interest are deleted every once in a while. See the discussion in [the question count sometimes decreases. why?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3731/5764) and the linked posts on Meta.SO.

Comment: @Werner True, I'd forgotten that discussion. From meta.SO it seems this only applies to questions with a score of <=0, have I understood that correctly?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Yes, however the "low interest" is defined. I'm confident this one won't be lost.